# Extracting values from a data frame based on index values in a list of tuples

Tags: python, pandas

[image]I have a dataframe from which I wish to extract values based on a list of tuples containing the indices for the values I need to extract from.  I also want to extract the corresponding column and row headings as well. Any ideas on how to do that.

Here is an example:

The data frame is the image shown

list of tuple: [(0,2),(1,0),(2,1)]

The objective is to use the first tuple to extract the value 40 and to extract the heading values in the form of a tuple (job 1, worker 2). And do the same for the next two tuples.

```
import pandas as pd
list_workers = ["Worker 1","worker 2","worker 3"]
list_jobs = ["Job 1","Job 2","Job 3"]
list_cost = [40,60,15,25,30,45,55,30,25]
indexes = [(0,2),(1,0),(2,1)]

#this section can be ignored: creates a matrix and adds it into a df
cost_arr = np.array(list_cost)
cost_mat = cost_arr.reshape(len(list_workers),len(list_jobs))
df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(cost_mat)],axis = 1)

#the image show is the resulting df
#to extract corresponding values from df for each tuple
for i in indexes:
    print (df.iat(i))
```

Comment: I think it would be nice if you edited your question to include a minimum working code that generates the data frame, as opposed to a photo of it. Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1, 2], 'b' : [3, 4]})
ls = [(0, 1), (1, 0)]
for i in ls:
    print(df.iloc[i[0], i[1]])
```

Comment: or just `print(df.iloc[i])`

Answer (score 1):

Following should work:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'W1':[1,2],'W2':[3,4]},index=["J1","J2"])
tuples=[(0,1),(1,0)]
values=[]
fieldNames=[]
for t in tuples:
  values.append(df.iloc[t[0],t[1]])
  fieldNames.append((df.index[t[0]],df.columns[t[1]]))
print(values)
print(fieldNames)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .iloc[] method for index based selection.

If you wish to loop through all of items;

```
for tuple in list_of_tuple:
    row, col = tuple[0], tuple[1]
    val = df.iloc[row, col]
```